# Как определить наличие класса хотя бы одного из элементов массива?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть массив из названий полей формы страницы регистрации (`id` этих полей). Полей может быть много. Для примера:

```
var params=['name', 'city', 'password'];
```

Как проверить что хотя бы одно из полей имеет класс `invalid` (универсальная функция,которая возвращает `false`, если хотя бы один элемент страницы с `id` из `params` имеет класс `invalid`), т.е.:

```
if($('#name').hasClass('invalid')||$('#city').hasClass('invalid')||$('#password').hasClass('invalid')) return false;
```

Как написать функцию:

```
function(params){
 /*что написать?*/
}
```

Comment: метод `some` у массива, как вариант

Comment: `/*что написать?*/` === `return $('form :input.invalid').length > 0`

Answer (score 1):

Через jQuery это можно сделать так:

```js
var result = false;
$.each(params, function(index, value) {
    if ($('#' + value).hasClass('invalid')) {
        result = true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Все аналогично Вашему сегодняшнему вопросу про `success`:

```js
var params = ['name', 'city', 'password'];
var validate = () => {
  let selector = params.map(p => `#${p}.invalid`).join(',');
  return document.querySelectorAll(selector).length === 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="name"></div>
<div id="city"></div>
<div id="password" class="invalid"></div>

<button onclick="console.log(validate())">validate</button>
```